# How to handle the unsigned types (especially u4) of a Java class file in a Java program?

Tags: java, jvm, bytecode, unsigned

From the [Java Virtual Machine specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html):

> A `class` file consists of a stream of 8-bit bytes. All 16-bit, 32-bit, and 64-bit quantities are constructed by reading in two, four, and eight consecutive 8-bit bytes, respectively. Multibyte data items are always stored in big-endian order, where the high bytes come first. In the Java platform, this format is supported by interfaces java.io.DataInput and `java.io.DataOutput` and classes such as java.io.DataInputStream and java.io.DataOutputStream.

> This chapter defines its own set of data types representing `class` file data: The types `u1`, `u2`, and `u4` represent an unsigned one-, two-, or four-byte quantity, respectively. In the Java platform, these types may be read by methods such as `readUnsignedByte`, `readUnsignedShort`, and `readInt` of the interface `java.io.DataInput`.

Aside from the irritating mentioning of "64-bit quantities" (there is no `u8`, [long and double](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.4.5) are splitted in two `u4` items), I don't understand how to handle the `u4` type.

For `u1` and `u2` it's clear:

- `u1`: read with `readUnsignedByte`, store in an `int`
- `u2`: read with `readUnsignedShort`, store in an `int`

The specification advises this:

- `u4`: read with `readInt`, store in an `int` (?)

What happens to values greater than [`Integer.MAX_VALUE`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#MAX_VALUE)? Does this advice silently imply that all values of type `u4` are less than or equal to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`?

I came up with this idea:

- `u4`: read with `readUnsignedInt`, store in a `long`

Unfortunalety, [there is no such method](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=4077352). But that's not the problem, since you can easily write your own:

```
public long readUnsignedInt() throws IOException {
    return readInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
}
```

So, here are two questionable spots:

1. The [Code attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.3):

> Code_attribute {
> ...
> u4 code_length;
> u1 code[code_length];
> ...
> }

Why is `code_length` not of type `u2`? [Later it says](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.9.1):

> The value of the `code_length` item must be less than 65536.

2. The [SourceDebugExtension attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.11):

> SourceDebugExtension_attribute {
> ...
> u4 attribute_length;
> u1 debug_extension[attribute_length];
> }
> ...
> *Note that the `debug_extension` array may denote a string longer than that which can be represented with an instance of class `String`.*

Why? Can `u4` values indeed exceed `Integer.MAX_VALUE` (since I think this is the maximum length of a `String` instance)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. To easily lift 64K code length restriction, if such a need arise.
2. Since there is no mention that u4 values cannot exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE, then one must assume that u4 values can exceed Integer.MAX_VALUE. JVM spec lefts nothing implicit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to process class files efficiently, you should not waste too much resources to solely hypothetical cases. As you’ve note yourself, the size of the code array is specified as `u4`, but the actually supported values are restricted to the `u2`. Likewise, all other `u4` size values are implicitly restricted, if you consider that the only officially supported ways of getting a class file into a JVM are based [on an array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-byte:A-int-int-java.security.ProtectionDomain-) or [on a `ByteBuffer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#defineClass-java.lang.String-java.nio.ByteBuffer-java.security.ProtectionDomain-), both being restricted to a signed `int` representing their total size.

Even if there was a way to get bigger class files into the JVM, there are other parts, [like the Instrumentation API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/instrument/ClassFileTransformer.html#transform-java.lang.ClassLoader-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-java.security.ProtectionDomain-byte:A-), expecting the possibility to convert a class back into an ordinary array. Even if a future JVM gets a real support for bigger class files, augmenting all APIs with alternatives using a new buffer type, your application, compiled today, is restricted to today’s APIs and buffer types.

So if the *total* size of a class file is intrinsically restricted to the maximum signed `int`, i.e. `2³¹` bytes, there is no need to consider the possibility of a *part* of the class file, like one attribute, being bigger than that. While you could form a theoretically correct class file with such a humongous attribute, even the JVM itself wouldn’t support it. There’s also no real life relevance for such scenarios.

So if the question isn’t how to handle them, the question is how to correctly reject them. If you are going to process a file, it could indeed have more than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` bytes, which you have to consider anyway, if you are going to read the file into a buffer for further processing. Then, checking the size before doing anything else and throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` would be appropriate. On a 32 Bit JVM, even throwing an `OutOfMemoryError` would be appropriate, as any real attempt to buffer the contents of that file would end up this way.

If the file is smaller than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or you are receiving the class file through an API that intrinsically limits the class file to be smaller than that, e.g. by passing an array or `ByteBuffer`, you can carry on and consider every `u4` size value being bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` as invalid, as it is denoting a size bigger than the class file itself. You don’t need a special `readUnsignedInt` method, as `int` and `u4` both have the same size, you only have to *interpret* the value correctly to sort out the values outside the valid positive `int` range.

With Java 8, this is especially easy:

```
int codeSize=bytebuffer.getInt();
if(Integer.compareUnsigned(codeSize, 65536)>0)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
        "invalid code size "+Integer.toUnsignedString(codeSize));
// carry on using the int value ordinarily
```

with earlier versions, you may consider that `u4` values greater than `Integer.MAX_VALUE` will appear as negative when being interpreted as `int`:

```
int codeSize=bytebuffer.getInt();
if(codeSize<0 || codeSize>65536)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid code size "+(codeSize&0xFFFFFFFFL));
// carry on using the int value ordinarily
```

Likewise, handle the other `u4` size values:

```
int size=bytebuffer.getInt();
// ByteBuffer can't be bigger than Integer.MAX_VALUE bytes:
if(size<0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "truncated class file (attribute size "+(size&0xFFFFFFFFL)+')');
// carry on using the int value ordinarily
```