# Read binary stream containing unsigned numbers

Tags: java, kotlin, jvm, binaryfiles, java-io

I want to read binary file containing 32-bit unsigned integers and 8-bit unsigned integers. I already know `DataInputStream` but its method `readInt` returns signed integers and there is no method for reading *unsigned* ints (there are such methods for 16-bit and 8-bit integers).

Reading separate bytes and concatenating them bitwise is the “official” way to do it? Would reading bytes into `ByteArray` and composing integers from them using bitshifts and bitwise `or`s significantly decrease performance?

Comment: Which result datatype do you want?

Comment: You can use `long value = Integer.toUnsignedLong​(dataInputStream.readInt());`, for example. Or you just use `int value = dataInputStream.readInt();` and *interpret* the value as unsigned whenever it makes a difference to the arithmetic. E.g. for `+`, `-`, and `*`, it makes no difference, for `/` and `%`, use [`Integer.divideUnsigned​(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#divideUnsigned(int,int)) and `remainderUnsigned​(…)`, likewise, `compareUnsigned​(…)` and `toUnsignedString​(…)`. This may solve a lot of use cases without `long` arithmetic.

Comment: For reading an 8-bit unsigned integer, use [readUnsignedByte](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/io/DataInputStream.html#readUnsignedByte()).

Comment: @VGR The OP did already acknowledge the existence of methods for 8 bit and 16 bit…

Comment: One reads the variables with the signed byte/short/int/long, and uses the available methods to reinterpete  them as unsigned as Holger said. In rare caes one uses a larger type like `int n = 0xFF &  signedByte;` or `long n = 0xFFFFL & signedInt;`

Comment: By the way the larger problem with reading numbers is the _order_ of the bytes. Java uses big endian, whereas on Windows the byte order is little endian for Intel. There are appropiate methods: `n = Integer.reverseBytes(n);`. Or better use a `ByteBuffer` with `order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)`

Comment: @JoopEggen the method `readUnsignedByte()` is actually implemented as `return 0xFF & readByte();`. Likewise, the `toUnsignedLong` method is implemented as `return x & 0xFFFF_FFFFL;` (but note that its eight `F`s not four), though some JVMs might replace it with an intrinsic operation when it fits. Most of the time when I need such things, I also use `ByteBuffer` instead of the old `DataInputStream`. Besides supporting other endianess, it allows slicing, bulk transfers, and interoperability with charset decoders…

Comment: @Holger The method `Integer.toUnsignedLong()` is the right thing I need. Could you post it as answer?

Comment: @JoopEggen My input is always BE so it should not cause any problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
long value = Integer.toUnsignedLong​(dataInputStream.readInt());
```

This is equivalent to the pre-Java 8 code

```
long value = dataInputStream.readInt() & 0xFFFFFFFFL;
```

The key point is that signed or unsigned are just different interpretations of the bit pattern, but to read the four byte quantity, `readInt()` is always sufficient. The operation above converts to a signed `long`, a datatype capable of covering all values of unsigned int.

But since the `int` does already hold all information, there is no need to convert it to a `long` immediately. The [Two’s Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement) used to represent the signed numbers even allows performing basic operations, i.e. `+`, `-`, and `*`, without differentiating between signed and unsigned numbers. For other operations, Java 8 introduced methods to perform them by interpreting the `int` value as unsigned:

- [`Integer.divideUnsigned​(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#divideUnsigned(int,int))
- [`Integer.remainderUnsigned​(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#remainderUnsigned(int,int))
- [`Integer.compareUnsigned​(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#compareUnsigned(int,int))
- [`Integer.toUnsignedString​(…)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Integer.html#toUnsignedString(int))

A practical example, I encountered, is parsing class files. These files have sized encoded as unsigned int at some place, but with most standard Java APIs, class files are delivered as byte array or `ByteBuffer` instances, which can not contain more than 2³¹ bytes. So dealing with larger numbers is an unnecessary complication for something that can’t be correct anyway, as a class file containing such a large size specification must be truncated.

So the code to handle this looks basically like:

```
int size = input.readInt();
if(Integer.compareUnsigned(size, Integer.MAX_VALUE)>0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "truncated class file (attribute size "+Integer.toUnsignedString(size)+')');
// just use the int value
```

or without Java 8 features
(even simpler, as long as the reader understands the [Two’s Complement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement)):

```
int size = input.readInt();
if(size < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException(
    "truncated class file (attribute size "+(size&0xFFFFFFFFL)+')');
// just use the int value
```

<sup>(see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41554166/2711488))</sup>